# How can I bring to start gridview's scroll bar in WinRT?

Tags: gridview, windows-8, windows-runtime, scrollbar

I want to bring to start my gridview's scroll bar in WinRT, Windows 8?

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by calling ScrollIntoView() and passing it the first item in your GridView.

```
yourGridView.ScrollIntoView(firstItemInYourGridView);
```